# Step into using GDB

Tags: gdb, buffer

I am performing some analysis of code using gdb. Just suppose the program is like

```
#include<stdio.h>

getinput()
{
    char buffer[8];
    gets(buffer);
    puts(buffer);
}
int main()
{
    getinput();
    return 0;
}
```

I have complied it using gcc withsome other switches as mentioned below:

```
gcc -ggdb -mpreferred-stack-boundary -fno-stack-protection -o demo demo.c
```

On analysis with gdb, when I insert break point on getinput() and gets(buffer) function..
Then using "s" step through  function.. on gets(buffer) function..

it does not ask for the user input, rather it asks for **userinput**. GDB directly steps into function gets...but i don't want it to move into gets functions..

```
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8048441: file demo.c, line 6.
(gdb) s
The program is not being run.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/BufferOverflow/demo 

Breakpoint 1, main () at demo.c:11
11      getinput();
(gdb) s

Breakpoint 2, getinput () at demo.c:6
6       gets(buffer);
(gdb) s
_IO_gets (buf=0xbfffeda8 "y\204\004\b") at iogets.c:32
32  iogets.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

I am getting the error shown above. Can anyone please help me regarding this  ???

Answer (score 0):

> Then using "s" step through function.. on gets(buffer) function..

Using `step` command on line 6 will step into `gets()` function. If you don't want this, use `next` command. It will move to the next line of code in `getinput()` function (to `puts()` call).

Answer (score 0):

gdb has a variety of ways to advance through a program.  An excellent overview can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html).

The most common sequence will be something like:

```
break [line or function/method] 
run  args  
next 
print [interesting variables]
```

The `next` will skip any function calls on the line and move to the next source line in the current function.  The `step` will step into a function.

If you accidentally step into a non-interesting function the `finish` command will run until the end of the current function.

A common case is stepping into a function that is evaluating an argument.

```
my_method(gets(buffer));
```

A step on this line will lead you into the assembler of the gets() function.  Usually this is not what you want. For such cases, I will usually just set a breakpoint on my_method and then `cont`.

gdb tries to avoid this situation with the `step-mode` setting.  It doesn't always work however as you see in your example.

gdb is a great tool that will save you time and misery.  If you are working as a developer then certainly take time to master it.